# How can I maximise binary cross entropy loss?

Tags: deep-learning, entropy, maximum-entropy, cross-entropy, multitask-learning

I have a multi-task learning model with two binary classification tasks.  One part of the model creates a shared feature representation that is fed into two subnets in parallel.  The loss function for each subnet at the moment is NLL, with a Softmax layer at the end of each.

I want to maximise the entropy in one task so the model doesn't/can't learn anything about that one task, and then I think the resulting accuracy for that task should be 50% i.e no better than chance.

Since I'm not an expert I've been advised (rightly or wrongly I haven't decided yet) one way to do this is use the cost function from a GAN discriminator to maximise the entropy for this particular task.

I've found the discriminator loss function in Goodfellow's GAN tutorial.  It looks like the y labels have been replaced with 0.5.  I'm using Torch and I can't see how this could be implemented, since I was presuming the y label for each sample could only be 0 or 1 when using the binary cross entropy loss function.

So far scouring the web hasn't been a great deal of help.  Can anyone shed any light with an answer?  Not so much on Torch implementation, rather the theory.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a question about Torch or more generally about how to maximize the loss irrespective of the software?

Comment: The latter, the implementation doesn't matter.